# Accidentally approved an edit that I meant to improve

Tags: support, review

I was given an edit to review that, although it was a slight improvement over the original, had a lot of bad grammar and generally was not very good quality (probably suggested by someone whose first language is not English).

I accidentally clicked on "*approve*" when I meant to chose "*improve*."

Am I correct that there is no way to either change the approval or improve the edit (until it's approved, at least)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct that there is no way to either change the approval or improve the edit (until it's approved, at least)?

Yes, the only thing you can do is **wait until the edit is accepted/rejected and then improve it**. It will be boring, so I suggest that you copy the content somewhere and do the improvements and then just apply them to the post.

[.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270537/trick-the-suggested-edit-queue-to-force-reject-items#comment89363_270540)

Comment: and you can always pop into [chat] and maybe get some help pushing it through review ;)